# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Streamer'

Tags: tweets

Since I want to do tweet analysis, I tried to use "Streamer" for tweet analysis.

So, I installed the package, but it keeps giving me this error.

Any solutions?

```
pip install --user Streamer

Requirement already satisfied: Streamer in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.1)

Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Streamer) (2.28.1)

Requirement already satisfied: BeautifulSoup4 in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Streamer) (4.11.1)

Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from BeautifulSoup4->Streamer) (2.3.1)

Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->Streamer) (1.26.11)

Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->Streamer) (2.0.4)

Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->Streamer) (3.3)

Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->Streamer) (2022.9.14)

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.






from Streamer import Streamer
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [19] in <cell line: 1>
    from Streamer import Streamer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Streamer'
```

Comment: Typo? `from streamer import Streamer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did the `pip install` it responded with `Requirement already satisfied: Streamer in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.1)`

This is telling you that is `Streamer` is already installed.

However, when you try to import it python complains that it is not found.

Check the permissions on the files/directories inside of `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages` (note you may need to adjust this location depending on your version and system).

I have found that pip sometimes creates files/dirs that are owned by root and not readable by anyone else.

You can fix this by using `chmod u+rw,go+r` for files and `chmod u+rwx,go+rx` for dirs.